# How to implement the equivalent of html:cancel in Struts 2?

Tags: html, jsp, struts2, tags, struts

I'm migrating an application from Struts1 to Struts2.

In Struts 1, we have `<html:cancel>` tag to bypass the form bean `validate()` method upon clicking.

But in Struts 2, I'm not aware of any similar tag available and I have a validate method in my `Action` class which automatically gets executed if you press the submit button.

So, how do I migrate the below tag to Struts2?

```
<html:cancel property="cancel" value="No"/>
```

Comment: There are multiple alternatives depending on what you actually want it to do; a submit button with an `action` property may be the easiest solution.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, the [`validation` interceptor](https://struts.apache.org/core-developers/validation-interceptor.html) is a method filter interceptor and by default it filters some method names like `cancel()`. If it doesn't then you can use `excludeMethods` parameter.

If you name your action method like this and map it to the button it will exclude from validation. The detailed information consists in my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24953588/573032).

Comment: If this answer helped to anyone then mark it as accepted answer. The checkbox is on the left of the answer.